# swagger-php response array of objects using attributes

Tags: php, arrays, object, attributes, swagger-php

Just learning to use attributes to describe function parameters and responses. I'm trying to describe a response object that returns an array of objects, but so far not a lot of luck using an array, this is what I have now, it returns an object, I would like it to be an array of objects:

```
#[OA\Response(
    response: 201,
    description: "Get the list",
    content: new OA\JsonContent(
        properties: [
            new OA\Property(
                property: "property name 1",
                type: "string",
                example: "value 1"
            ),
            new OA\Property(
                property: "property name 2",
                type: "string",
                example: "value 2"
            )
        ],
        type: 'object'
    )
)]
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical way would be to use a reference of your object schema (if you have).
For example, something like https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/using-links-php81/RepositoriesController.php#L16

If you prefer to inline the object properties, it should be similar to this (untested):

```
<?php

use OpenApi\Attributes as OA;

#[OA\Get(path: '/api/get')]
#[OA\Response(
    response: 201,
    description: "Get the list",
    content: new OA\JsonContent(
        type: 'array',
        items: new OA\Items(
        // your list item
            type: 'object',
            properties: [
                new OA\Property(
                    property: "property name 1",
                    type: "string",
                    example: "value 1"
                ),
                new OA\Property(
                    property: "property name 2",
                    type: "string",
                    example: "value 2"
                )
            ]
        )
    )
)]
class Controller
{
}
```

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you so much DerManoMan!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an object is a separate class with its own Open API schema, you can declare it as shown below:

```
#[OA\Property(
        type: 'array',
        items: new OA\Items(
            oneOf: [
                new OA\Schema(ref: '#/components/schemas/CarsResult'),
                new OA\Schema(ref: '#/components/schemas/TrucksResult'),
            ]
        ),
        nullable: false
    )]
```